# How to strip all dictionaries from an orderedDictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a dictionary with some keys pointing to ordered dictionaries and some keys pointing to strings how do I strip away all the ordered dictionaries and store them into a separate dictionary.

Comment: Your going to have to be a bit more specfic in your problem description. Better yet, could you show some code?

Comment: loop through, test if the value is a dictionary, if it is, add it to a different dictionary... pretty sure you can do in a oneliner

Comment: Use `isinstance(value, OrderedDict)` to check types

Comment: Would all the OrderedDict's be stored under one key?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> mixed_dict = {'a': 'b', 'c': OrderedDict([('d', 'e')])}
>>> {k: v for k, v in mixed_dict.items() if isinstance(v, OrderedDict)}
{'c': OrderedDict([('d', 'e')])}
>>> {k: v for k, v in mixed_dict.items() if not isinstance(v, OrderedDict)}
{'a': 'b'}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to filter out everything that is not a `OrderedDict` using dict comprehension:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = {'a': 'b', 'c':OrderedDict([('a', 'data1')]), 'd': OrderedDict([('a', 'data1')])}
>>> res = {key : value for key, value in d.items() if isinstance(value, OrderedDict)}
>>> res
{'c': OrderedDict([('a', 'data1')]), 'd': OrderedDict([('a', 'data1')])}
>>>
```